# Server returns HTML but I cant inject onto site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        action: 'mypages_subscription_slider',
        subs: subscriptions,
    },
    success: function (data) {
        build_subscription_slider(subscriptions);
    },
});
```

I check my network tab, and file that I recieve from server has correct content. Like this:

```
<hr>
<div class="sub-slider">

    <div class="slider">
    <div class="sub-box"><div class="title">1 GB</div>
    </div>

    <div class="sub-slider-confirmation-btn-wrp">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="sub-slider-confirmation-btn">Välj</div>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
<hr>
```

And now I want to use this markup to insert it into a div on my page, like so:

```
function build_subscription_slider(subscriptions) {
    $('.sub-slider-section').append($(subscriptions));
}
```

On my page the div to get inserted html simply looks like this:

```
<div class="sub-slider-section">          
</div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're appending `$(data)`, yet the argument is `subscriptions`. Presumably that's a typo and your code should be `.append(subscriptions);`...?

Comment: Side note: This is a good opportunity to take a look at the browser's development console.  It is telling you what the error is.  Always check your tools first.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues above.

In your success callback in your `ajax` request you want to pass in data to your `build_subscription_slider` function as below.

```
success: function (data) {
    build_subscription_slider(data);
},
```

And then you want to append the argument passed in `subscriptions`.

```
function build_subscription_slider(subscriptions) {
    $('.sub-slider-section').append(subscriptions);
}
```

Comment: You are correct, 2h debugging for this. I take a break now!

Comment: Just a small correction to your answer. `$().append();` function wants a jquery object not a html string. So correct answer is: `$('.sub-slider-section').append($(subscriptions));`. Thanks

Comment: `$().append(); function wants a jquery object not a html string` That's not true at all. A string is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, says I need to wait 5 more minutes :)